# RichEmbed builder not adding field

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Basically, what the title says, fields are not being added to my embed. This is my code:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle('Help')
  .setDescription('Available Commands')
  .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL)
  .setColor('#3fa8ff')
// .setTimestamp()

console.log(categories);

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  var tempDesc = '';
  for (var c in commands) {
    if (categories[i] === commands[c].category) {
      tempDesc += `${commands[c]} - ${commands[c].description} - ${commands[c].usage}\n`;
    }
  }
  embed.addField(categories[i], tempDesc);
}

message.channel.send({
  embed
});
```

I have tried to comment out things like `.setTimestamp()`, but nothing works.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was being stupid and got lists and arrays mixed up.